# Can you explain about this Error Message?

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, web

I made 2 file of php :

1. class.datebase.php
2. class.ManageDatabase.php

this file I used for connect to database...but I got error...

can you help me..

**class.database.php :**

```
<?php 

include_once ( '../config.php' );

class database {
    protected $db_conn;
    public $db_name = DB_NAME;
    public $db_host = DB_HOST;
    public $db_user = DB_USER;
    public $db_pass = DB_PASS;      
}

function connect(){
        try { 
             $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
             return $this->db_conn;         
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
             return $e->getMessage();           
    }           
}

  ?>
```

**class.ManageDatabase.php :**

```
<?php 

  class ManageDatabase{ 
      public $link;

      function __construct(){
          include_once( 'class.database.php' );
          $conn = new database;
          $this->link = $conn->connect();
          return $this->link;   
      }
  }

  $something = new ManageDatabase;
  echo $something;
?>
```

and for error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method database::connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myweb\crud\core\class.ManageDatabase.php on line 9
```

Comment: connect() is not a member of class database.

Comment: Thank's...
How fool I am :)

Answer (score 3):

Put the connect function in the Database class, not out of it (in this file: class.database.php)

Answer (score 0):

the function connect is defined outside the class database

```
class database {
    protected $db_conn;
    public $db_name = DB_NAME;
    public $db_host = DB_HOST;
    public $db_user = DB_USER;
    public $db_pass = DB_PASS;      
// don't close the class here

function connect(){
        try { 
             $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
             return $this->db_conn;         
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
             return $e->getMessage();           
    }           
}
} //close it here
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple...
You've gotta change this:

```
class database {
protected $db_conn;
public $db_name = DB_NAME;
public $db_host = DB_HOST;
public $db_user = DB_USER;
public $db_pass = DB_PASS; 


}

function connect(){
        try { 
             $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
             return $this->db_conn;         
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
             return $e->getMessage();           
    }

}
```

to

```
class database {
    protected $db_conn;
    public $db_name = DB_NAME;
    public $db_host = DB_HOST;
    public $db_user = DB_USER;
    public $db_pass = DB_PASS;

function connect(){
        try { 
             $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
             return $this->db_conn;         
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
             return $e->getMessage();           
        }           
    }      
}
```

You closed your class before the function, so when you called the function inside the class, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You're connect function should be a method of the class:

```
class database {
    protected $db_conn;
    public $db_name = DB_NAME;
    public $db_host = DB_HOST;
    public $db_user = DB_USER;
    public $db_pass = DB_PASS;      

    function connect(){
        try { 
             $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host = $this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
             return $this->db_conn;         
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
             return $e->getMessage();           
        }           
    }
}
```